# Ember App Kit project vendor folder empty

Tags: javascript, ember.js, gruntjs, bower, ember-app-kit

Currently I am trying to start a project with EmberJS. And from what I found on the internet Ember App Kit is a nice "template" to kick start an application.

So I followed the [getting started guide](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/getting-started.html) but I am running into a problem.

I have installed npm, bower and grunt and run all the commands given on that page. But my vendor folder stays empty. So when start everything with `grunt server` and go to my browser to `localhost:8000` it shows nothing (and I get a bunch of 404 for the vendor libraries (e.g jQuery, Ember and so on).

I have found that they are place here in public/js/libs instead of /vendor (this folder does exist though) and I could change the address in the index.html to point to there. But I don't think that is what I am supposed to do.

Did I do something wrong, or did I forget something.

Comment: use yeoman ember generator rather app kit...its not official one...

Comment: Well that was my original idea, but on the Yeoman site it said that that was deprecated (when you search for the ember generator) and to use ember app kit instead. http://yeoman.io/community-generators.html - edit: it seems that the deprecated version points to the official one so now rolling with that. thanks. https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember

Comment: What is inside of your `.bowerrc` file? There should be a directory-path.

Comment: worth a mention if you are new - I wrote a blog series on how to build your own EAK-Lite (showing how the Gruntfile got to the end result essentially) http://www.toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2014/04/06/Building-your-own-ember-app-kit-lite/

Answer (score 1):

For me this was fixed by running Bower as root (I probably installed it in a wrong way earlier), which fetched the deps correctly (and into the /vendor directory as defined in .bowerrc).

```
sudo bower install --allow-root
```

Bower specifically discourages this approach:

> Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
>   If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.
>
> http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
>
> https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the `.browerrc` when you copy files?

If `.browerrc` file not exist, dependencies will be installed to `bower_components` folder not `vendor`, this file is hidden in OS X Finder by default (because the "." prefix).